# When tried to get User's friend list on FB, it gives total numbers of friends only instead to give a friend list.. Why this happening?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

When i tried to retrieve the user's friends list with permission "public_profile" it gives me just my total number of friends on FB, not a list. Logcat showing null on list variable.. Can somebody tell me what's the reason behind this ??

Answer (score 0):

There is literally no possible way, at all, to get a users full friend list on Facebook (including your own).

It was possible about a year or 2 ago, but Facebook changed their API and now there is no way to do so.

Comment: that is not entirely true, see duplicate question: taggable_friends and invitable_friends do return all friends, but only for very specific tasks (tagging and inviting).